# Gráfica de barras con dodge y fill en r

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráficas

Estoy tratando de realizar un gráfico de barras con `ggplot()` por ejemplo el código:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) + 
    geom_bar(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "total"))
```

Crea un gráfico de barras donde el factor en el eje x es el cilindraje (cyl) y a su vez dentro de cada factor de cyl se divide por el factor (vs) ahora bien, yo realicé una nueva agrupación con la data

```
 mtcars %>% 
     group_by(cyl) %>% 
     summarise(hp=mean(hp),drat=mean(drat))
```

Y deseo que la gráfica de barras sustituya el factor (vs) por las 2 columnas nuevas es decir hp y drat, tanto para una posición dodge como una fill, creo que la gran diferencia es que en el primer ejemplo el factor se encuentra en una columna y ahora el factor se divide en dos columnas.

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(hp=mean(hp),drat=mean(drat)) %>% 
  gather(variable, valor, -cyl) %>%                      #Alargo los datos, así puedo usar `cyl` como variable de grupo fill
    ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = valor, fill = variable )) +  #Paso explícitamente el mapeo de y
    geom_col(position="dodge")                           #geom_col() porque estoy pasando los valores de y, en lugar de calcularlos directamente en el ggplot
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La diferencia con el código original es que:

- ya están calculados los valores de y, así que hay que mapearlos en `aes()`
- Hay que "alargar" los datos, de modo que una columna sirva para `fill`
- Por eso se usa `geom_col()` y no `geom_bar()`. El segundo asume que se necesita calcular los conteos, y no es tu caso.

> Nota **aparte**: no es buena idea presentar comparaciones de medias con gráficos de barras, porque muestran solamente el estimador puntual (la media) y no dan cuenta de la incertidumbre de la estimación (errores estándar o algo por el estilo). Para ese caso sería mejor un boxplot o una superposición de kernel de densidad.

Comment: Concuerdo con tu Nota, y además mencionaría que miden cosas distintas, con escalas que no guardan relación una con otro, no sé si un gráfico de barras es la mejor opción.